# What sql should be used for inventory tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a MySQL db set up like so,

user_table table

- user_ID PK
- username
- password
- email
- level
- location

game_items table

- game_item_is PK
- item_name

user_inventory table

- user_inventory_id PK
- user_id FK
- game_item_id FK
- quantity

This is a db for a game i am building and i am trying to code an sql query to get the following data out of the db:

- Level
- Location
- A list of game items the user has associated to their user_id

The data i already have is the user_id and username.
So how would i go about creating this sql statement? would i use joins? if so where?

I want to get every game_item the user has associated with their account so would this include * anywhere?

Thanks

Comment: Please show us what you already tried. This way we will have at least some idea of your familiarity with SQL in general and MySql in particular.

Comment: Thanks for your input, after a while playing with the SQL on phpMyAdmin i found the result i was after, see answer

Answer (score 1):

Ok so after a while playing with the sql on phpmyadmin i got the result i wanted, if anyone would like to know here is the code:

```
SELECT ut.username, ut.level, ut.location, ui.quantity, ui.game_item_id
FROM user_table ut, user_inventory ui
WHERE ut.user_id = ui.user_id
AND ut.user_id =1
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, just select the level and location in one query and the inventory items in another

```
SELECT level, location FROM user_table WHERE id = ..

SELECT * FROM user_inventory WHERE id = ..
```

Comment: Thanks for your input, after a while playing with the SQL on phpMyAdmin i found the result i was after, see answer